# Use inner join if record exists otherwise use left join

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have the following table structure:

dbo.Owner

```
OwnerID   OwnerName  
  1        John   
  2        Marie
  3        Alex
```

and dbo.Pet

```
PetID PetTag Status OwnerID
  1    A341  Active    1  
  2    A342  Inactive  1  
  3    A343  Active    2
  4    A345  Active    2
```

I need to return all owners who have only Active pets or no pets.

So in this example above I need to Return Owner 2 (All pets are active) and Owner 3 (No pets)

I will be pulling data in C# using Entity Framework but plain SQL will be sufficient.

Here's what I came up with so far:

```
select mi.* from Owner o
join Pet p
on o.OwnerID= p.OwnerID
where o.Status='Active'
union select * from Owner
where OwnerID not in (select OwnerID from Pet)
```

Now, this query above works but it includes OwnerID = 1. and Also I was wondering if there's a way to do this in 1 query without union.

Comment: Listen to your plain english query: *I need to return all owners who have only Active pets or no pets.* You need a simple union of those who have active pets and those who have no pets.

Answer (score 5):

If your only values for `Status` are "Active" and "Inactive", you can actually simplify your query. When you say:

> I need to return all owners who have only Active pets or no pets.

This would then actually translate to:

> I need to return all owners who have no Inactive pets.

Then your query becomes much easier.

In an Entity Framework query:

```
owners = context.Owners
    .Where(o => !o.Pets.Any(p => p.Status == "Inactive"))
    .ToList();
```

The SQL query generated by this is:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[OwnerID] AS [OwnerID], 
    [Extent1].[OwnerName] AS [OwnerName]
    FROM [dbo].[Owners] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Pets] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[OwnerID] = [Extent2].[OwnerID]) AND (N'Inactive' = [Extent2].[Status])
    )
```

Or to remove the clutter:

```
SELECT 
    OwnerID,
    OwnerName
    FROM Owners o
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
        1
        FROM Pets p
        WHERE (o.OwnerID = p.OwnerID AND p.Status = 'Inactive')
    )
```

---

**If you have more values for Status**, you could use (Entity Framework):

```
owners = context.Owners
    .Where(o => o.Pets.Any(p => p.Status == "Active") || !o.Pets.Any())
    .Where(o => !o.Pets.Any(p => p.Status == "Inactive" /* || p.Status == "Lost" and any other values */))
    .ToList();
```

which would generate the SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[OwnerID] AS [OwnerID], 
    [Extent1].[OwnerName] AS [OwnerName]
    FROM [dbo].[Owners] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Pets] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[OwnerID] = [Extent2].[OwnerID]) AND (N'Active' = [Extent2].[Status])
    )) OR ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Pets] AS [Extent3]
        WHERE [Extent1].[OwnerID] = [Extent3].[OwnerID]
    ))) AND ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Pets] AS [Extent4]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[OwnerID] = [Extent4].[OwnerID]) AND (N'Inactive' = [Extent4].[Status])
    ))
```

You'd want to test that for performance and there may well be better ways, but it gives the desired result. It does assume you have foreign key/navigation property though.

Comment: What will happen if one person have one ACTIVE and also one INACTIVE pet both at same time.. I think your query won't work on that condition

Comment: Those owners will be omitted by both queries, which is what the question specified. Unless I'm misunderstanding you?

Answer (score 4):

Try [the following query](http://rextester.com/YNHSV31041):

```
select o.*
from dbo.owner o
where not exists(
  select *
  from dbo.pet p
  where p.ownerid=o.ownerid and
    p.status='Inactive'
);
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei, this should work. But what if there are more statuses? Can I change p.Status = 'Inactive' to p.Status <> 'Active' ?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  OwnerID, OwnerName 
FROM Owner 
WHERE OwnerID NOT IN (
SELECT OwnerID from Pet
WHERE Status='Inactive'
```

This simple query will do the thing.

```
OwnerId        OwnerName 
2              Marie
3              Alex
```

And if you want to select owner with atleast one ACTIVE or NO PET then use the below query.

```
SELECT o.OwnerID o.OwnerName
FROM Owner o 
LEFT JOIN Pet p 
ON o.OwnerID= p.OwnerID 
AND (p.Status='Active' 
OR p.OwnerID is NULL)

OwnerId        OwnerName
1              John
2              Marie
3              Alex
```

This query will return OWNER name until that Owner's all pets are INACTIVE

Now for another case..

If there is a chance for your table to have OwnerId as NULL in Pets Table.
Kindly use the below Query. (Mysql)

```
SELECT OwnerID, OwnerName 
FROM Owner 
WHERE OwnerID NOT IN (
   SELECT IFNULL(OwnerID,0) from Pet
   WHERE Status='Inactive');
```

ADDED IFNULL() in subquery.

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/164b1/2)

Comment: As a general rule, avoid `NOT IN` if you can. If there will ever be NULLs in the `Pet.OwnerID` column (i.e., pets with no owners), your query will turn into a pumpkin. The `not exists` version of @AndreiOdegov is not susceptible to this.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT OwnerName 
    FROM Owner 
    WHERE OwnerID NOT IN (
       SELECT IFNULL(OwnerID,0) from Pet
       WHERE Status='Inactive');

I added IFNULL to the select in NOT IN and it is working.

Comment: Also, because Owner is unique on OwnerId there's no need for the DISTINCT, it might do an unnecessary unique sort. I wouldn't remove the ID, because multiple people can have the same name.

Comment: Removed distinct and added id

Comment: @FarazPV, there is no `ifnull()` function in MS SQL Server. Also, have you compared the execution plans of your solution and the one with `not exists`? I bet you lose sargability with a wrapper such as this.

Comment: My SQL IFNULL()

MSSql ISNULL()

Execution time and plan is available in the fiddle

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly it is possible to do this with a LEFT JOIN. I've no idea about whether this performs differently to the NOT EXISTs queries suggested by other answers.

```
CREATE TABLE [Owner] (
    OwnerID int PRIMARY KEY,
    OwnerName nvarchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO [Owner]
VALUES
  (1, 'John'), 
  (2, 'Marie'),
  (3, 'Alex');

CREATE TABLE Pet (
    PetID int PRIMARY KEY, 
    PetTag nvarchar(10), 
    Status nvarchar(30), 
    OwnerID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Owner](OwnerID)
);

INSERT INTO Pet
VALUES
  (1,'A341','Active', 1),  
  (2,'A342','Inactive', 1),  
  (3,'A343','Active', 2),
  (4,'A345','Active', 2);

SELECT * FROM [Owner];
SELECT * FROM Pet;

SELECT
    o.*
FROM
    [Owner] o
    LEFT JOIN Pet p
        ON o.OwnerID = p.OwnerID
        AND p.Status <> 'Active'
WHERE
    p.OwnerID IS NULL;

DROP TABLE Pet, [Owner];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select DISTINCT 
     o.Id 
FROM Owner o
LEFT JOIN Pet p ON o.OwnerID= p.OwnerID
where p.Status='Active' OR p.OwnerID IS NULL
```

Comment: Incorrect. This will return owner with id 1 also. Needs to return those owners who ONLY have active pets.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT RESULT FROM (
                            SELECT    CASE WHEN POID is NULL 
                                           THEN OID
                                           WHEN OID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT 
                                                            OwnerID from Pet 
                                                            WHERE Status='Inactive')
                                           THEN OID
                                      END AS RESULT
                            FROM (
                                     SELECT O.OwnerID as OID, P.OwnerID as POID
                                     FROM Owner o 
                                     LEFT JOIN Pet p 
                                     ON o.OwnerID= p.OwnerID 
                                  ) T
                            )T2 WHERE  RESULT IS NOT NULL
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1acad/15)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting that although you tagged it entity-framework, most answers don't come up with the simplifications that entity-framework offers you.

There is a one-to-many relationship between `Owners` and `Pets`. Every `Owner` has zero or more `Pets`, every `Pet` belongs to exactly one `Owner`.

If you have configured your entity framework classes correctly for a [one-to-many relationship](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx), they will be like:

```
class Owner
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    // every Owner has zero or more Pets:
    public virtual ICollection<Pet> Pets {get; set;}

    ... // other properties
}
class Pet
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    // every Pet belongs to exactly one Owner, using foreign key:
    public int OwnerId {get; set;}
    public Owner Owner {get; set;}
}
class MyDbConnection : DbConnection
{
    public DbSet<Owner> Owners {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Pet> Pets {get; set;}
}
```

This is enough for entity framework to recognize that you designed the one-to-many relationship. Whenever needed, entity framework will do the correct join for you.

> I need to return all owners who have only Active pets or no pets.

This is the same collections as:

> I need to return all owners who don't have Inactive pets

(note to self: Owners without Pets, surely don't have Inactive Pets!)

If you've set up the classes correctly, the queries will be much more readable. You can think of collections, instead of tables that are related towards each other using IDs

```
using (var dbConnection = new MyDbConnection())
{
    var requestedOwners = dbConnection.Owners              // Give me all Owners
        .Where(owner => !owner.Pets.Any()                  // that have no Pets at all
          || owner.Pets.All(pet => pet.Status == Active)); // or have only active Pets
}
```

Entity Framework will recognize that this needs a join and will translate this into the correct inner joins for you.

The second query is even simpler, and probably faster because you can continue to the next `Owner` as soon as an Inactive `Pet` is found

```
var ownersWithoutInactivePets = dbContext.Owners   // give me all Owners
    .Where(owner => !owner.Pets                    // that don't have
        .Any(pet => pet.Status == Inactive);       // any inactive Pets
```

Again, entity framework will do the join for you